# Show little part of big div by element position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I'm trying to create a map and its size is 576 x 576.

It's created by tiles which are 32 x 32. So what I want is to find my character div inside this map and give me a view of it. Like no matter where my character position is, show always only 150 x 150 view of it. Like game moving changing sight. My character always stays on center and give around him 150 x 150 view of this whole big 576 x 576 div.

```css
.row {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.texture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.texture {
    position: relative;
}

.texture:hover {
    position: relative;
    filter: grayscale(1);
}

.char {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>

</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs">   <div class="char"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/8PZ6Dp9/hero-down.png" alt="hero"></div></div>
<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>

</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>

</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
<div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>

</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle with a full-sized map](https://jsfiddle.net/relos100/03zdxqa9/14/).

Comment: Questions are expected to be self-contained.  Please copy the logic from your fiddle into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use a few divs and manipulate the central one's margins.

```js
$("#up").on("click", function(e)
{
  var offset = parseInt($("#map").css("margin-top"));
  offset+=16;
  $("#map").css("margin-top", offset + "px");
});

$("#down").on("click", function(e)
{
  var offset = parseInt($("#map").css("margin-top"));
  offset-=16;
  $("#map").css("margin-top", offset + "px");
});

$("#left").on("click", function(e)
{
  var offset = parseInt($("#map").css("margin-left"));
  offset+=16;
  $("#map").css("margin-left", offset + "px");
});

$("#right").on("click", function(e)
{
  var offset = parseInt($("#map").css("margin-left"));
  offset-=16;
  $("#map").css("margin-left", offset + "px");
});
```

```css
.row {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.texture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.texture:hover {
    position: relative;
    filter: grayscale(1);
}

button
{
  font-size: 20pt;width: 50px;height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:right">
<table>
    <tr><td></td><td><button id="up">&uarr;</button><br /></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="left">&larr;</button><br /></td><td></td><td><button id="right">&rarr;</button><br /></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><button id="down">&darr;</button><br /></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="viewport" style="width:300px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/8PZ6Dp9/hero-down.png" alt="hero" style="position:absolute;left:140px;top:140px;">
<div id="map" style="width:590px; height:433px;">

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want to do. But can I ask you one more time. Is this possible to make this code technique on my html? I generate my map from 32x32 small images with flex, row. In your example is everything perfect what I want, only one thing that is map is one image.

Comment: When I wrap my container in id=map, than whole container just resizes to 300px x 300px, not changes just viewport. Resizes everyting. I think it's because that I generate my terrain with flex. See on fiddle, if you can you will understand.

Comment: The problem with your demo is that all of your textures are the same. Can you modify your demo to have different pieces? At the moment, if you were scrolling you wouldn't be able to tell...

Comment: What do you mean? You mean just different images of 32x32 tiles? Or classes names? Witch parts I need to change? You see, my idea is generate all of this HTML from array. Every 32x32 px div is from array. And what gonna changes, only classes names, to get different 32x32 tiles. Most of this could be just grass, than on top of this like rocks and something like that. I almost created all of this. But only this problem left with viewport. Just sitting for hours and can't find a way or even google it :)

Comment: Do you have any other tiles other than https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png ?

Comment: Yes, I have upload a few more. https://i.ibb.co/tCd8TRH/untitled.png, https://i.ibb.co/kyFxf4g/untitled2.png,  https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png, https://i.ibb.co/DGHxs21/untitled4.png

Comment: Updated. Now with a few different tiles.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm gonna rework with this and made what I wanted :) U just saved me!

Comment: Hey. Sorry for being a little anoying... But maybe is it possible to get margins if u click on some map tile? I mean not using arrows only, but if I click on specific tile to somehow get margins to come to wanted place at one click? That would be just perfect for this map logic. Thanks :)

Comment: No worries. You mean if you click on a square, then move to that square?

Comment: Yes. Exactly this:)

Comment: Please create a new question and we can work on it there.

Comment: Its here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634347/move-charachter-on-map-on-clicked-position