# Move character on map on clicked position

Tags: jquery, html, css, dictionary, margin

I've got a map which is can be moved around by changing `margin-top` and `margin-left` logic. When I click on arrows, jQuery changes the left/top margins and the whole map moves, so it looks like my character is moving.

Now I want to be able to move to anywhere I click on specified map position.

```js
$("#up").on("click", function(e)
{
  var offset = parseInt($("#map").css("margin-top"));
  offset+=16;
  $("#map").css("margin-top", offset + "px");
});

$("#down").on("click", function(e)
{
  var offset = parseInt($("#map").css("margin-top"));
  offset-=16;
  $("#map").css("margin-top", offset + "px");
});

$("#left").on("click", function(e)
{
  var offset = parseInt($("#map").css("margin-left"));
  offset+=16;
  $("#map").css("margin-left", offset + "px");
});

$("#right").on("click", function(e)
{
  var offset = parseInt($("#map").css("margin-left"));
  offset-=16;
  $("#map").css("margin-left", offset + "px");
});
```

```css
.row {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.texture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.texture:hover {
    position: relative;
    filter: grayscale(1);
}

button
{
  font-size: 20pt;width: 50px;height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:right">
<table>
    <tr><td></td><td><button id="up">&uarr;</button><br /></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="left">&larr;</button><br /></td><td></td><td><button id="right">&rarr;</button><br /></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><button id="down">&darr;</button><br /></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="viewport" style="width:300px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/8PZ6Dp9/hero-down.png" alt="hero" style="position:absolute;left:140px;top:140px;">
<div id="map" style="width:590px; height:433px;">

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part is to work out which cell you clicked on and then to work out the x and y coordinates. Once that is deduced we work out the differential from the starting point (since we start at 4, 4). We then animate to the desired cell.

From here you could animate your character when he moves. You could also work out the distance to travel and to change the speed of movement. At present the speed is always 1 second to get to the destination.

```js
$("#up").on("click", function(e)
{
  var offset = parseInt($("#map").css("margin-top"));
  offset+=16;
  $("#map").css("margin-top", offset + "px");
});

$("#down").on("click", function(e)
{
  var offset = parseInt($("#map").css("margin-top"));
  offset-=16;
  $("#map").css("margin-top", offset + "px");
});

$("#left").on("click", function(e)
{
  var offset = parseInt($("#map").css("margin-left"));
  offset+=16;
  $("#map").css("margin-left", offset + "px");
});

$("#right").on("click", function(e)
{
  var offset = parseInt($("#map").css("margin-left"));
  offset-=16;
  $("#map").css("margin-left", offset + "px");
});

$("#map div img").on("click", function(e)
{
  var $div = $(this).closest("div");
  var x = $div.index();
  
  var $row = $div.closest("div.row");
  var y = $row.index();
  
  var dx = (4- x) * 32, dy = (4- y) * 32
  
  $( "#map" ).animate({
    "margin-left" : dx + "px",
    "margin-top": dy + "px"
  }, 1000, function() 
  {

  });
});
```

```css
.row {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.texture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.texture:hover {
    position: relative;
    filter: grayscale(1);
}

button
{
  font-size: 20pt;width: 50px;height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:right">
<table>
    <tr><td></td><td><button id="up">&uarr;</button><br /></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="left">&larr;</button><br /></td><td></td><td><button id="right">&rarr;</button><br /></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><button id="down">&darr;</button><br /></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="viewport" style="width:300px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/8PZ6Dp9/hero-down.png" alt="hero" style="position:absolute;left:128px;top:128px;">
<div id="map" style="width:590px; height:433px;">

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZVsfZgZ/untitled3.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/4.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/1.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
  <div class="texture"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVFs8x/0.png" alt="bbs"></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you so much for spending your time for me! For real, you helped me alot! :)

Comment: No worries. Try to analyse the code to work out what's going on.

Comment: I will! I just started to focus more on front-end about one or two moths ago, so I'm still weak, but I'm trying to get more and more information! :)